# ODATA WebService, get $metadata C#

Tags: c#, metadata, odata

I have a WebService that expose this `$metadata`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="true"?>
<edmx:Edmx xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx" Version="1.0">     > <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0"
xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">

<Schema xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices"
Namespace="NAV"> 
<EntityType Name="PAsset"> 
<Key> <PropertyRef Name="No"/> </Key>  <Property Name="No" Nullable="false" Type="Edm.String"/>  <Property Name="Description"
Nullable="true" Type="Edm.String"/>  <Property Name="Inactive"
Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Boolean"/>  <Property Name="Insured"
Nullable="false" Type="Edm.Boolean"/> </EntityType> 

<EntityType Name="PAssetsDepreciationBook">

<EntityType Name="PBankAPostGrp">
<EntityType Name="PCompany">
<EntityType Name="PCustomer">
```

Is possible get the information in this `$metadata` in a C# aplication?

I Have a Application with a reference to the Service working, and some code i'm using:

> uriString = String.Format("PAssetsDepreciationBook?$filter=FA_No eq
>   '{0}'",cliente);
>
> contex = new ServiceReference1.NAV(new Uri(serviceEndPoint));
>   contex.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
>
> var customers = contex.Execute(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.Relative));
>
> foreach (var c in customers)
>   {
>      result = result + c.Acquisition_Cost;
>   }
>   return result;

This works fine, but to get `$metadata` doesn't.

Answer (score 5):

There is already code (mostly) to do this. It involves the *ODataMessageReader.ReadMetadataDocument()* call:

```
var request = WebRequest.CreateHttp(baseUrl + "$metadata");
var metadataMessage =
    new ClientHttpResponseMessage((HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse());
using (var messageReader = new ODataMessageReader(metadataMessage))
{
    IEdmModel edmModel = messageReader.ReadMetadataDocument();
    // Do stuff with edmModel here
}
```

You need the ClientHttpResponseMessage class but that is simple (from [ODataLib101](http://odatasamples.codeplex.com/)):

```
public class ClientHttpResponseMessage : IODataResponseMessage
{
    private readonly HttpWebResponse webResponse;

    public ClientHttpResponseMessage(HttpWebResponse webResponse)
    {
        if (webResponse == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("webResponse");
        this.webResponse = webResponse;
    }

    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, string>> Headers
    {
        get
        {
            return this.webResponse.Headers.AllKeys.Select(
                headerName => new KeyValuePair<string, string>(
                   headerName, this.webResponse.Headers.Get(headerName)));
        }
    }

    public int StatusCode
    {
        get { return (int)this.webResponse.StatusCode; }
        set
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException(
                "The HTTP response is read-only, status code can't be modified on it.");
        }
    }

    public Stream GetStream()
    {
        return this.webResponse.GetResponseStream();
    }

    public string GetHeader(string headerName)
    {
        if (headerName == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("headerName");
        return this.webResponse.Headers.Get(headerName);
    }

    public void SetHeader(string headerName, string headerValue)
    {
        throw new InvalidOperationException(
            "The HTTP response is read-only, headers can't be modified on it.");
    }
}
```

With the IEdmModel, you can access all the information in the metadata to do things like build a dictionary of type->controller name:

```
Dictionary<type, string> typeControllerMap =
    edmModel.SchemaElements.OfType<IEdmEntityContainer>()
            .Single()
            .Elements.OfType<IEdmEntitySet>()
            .Select(es => new { t = FindType(es.ElementType.FullName()), n = es.Name })
            .Where(tn => tn.t != null)
            .ToDictionary(tn => tn.t, tn => tn.n);
```

The *FindType()* call in the middle of the LINQ chain above simply searches all assemblies for a type given the type name:

```
private static Type FindType(string fullName)
{
    return
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()
            .Where(a => !a.IsDynamic)
            .SelectMany(a => a.GetTypes())
            .FirstOrDefault(t => t.FullName.Equals(fullName));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can request the metadata as a plain XML using `HttpWebRequest` for example. If you need to parse it, you can use `EdmLib` (`Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll`) which can be found on `NuGet` or even better `ODataLib` (`Microsoft.Data.OData.dll`) also on `Nuget` which has `ODataMessageReader`.`ReadMetadataDocument` specifically designed to read these (it still returns the EDM object model for it, it just deals with the `EDMX` wrapper and versioning for you).

Answer (score 1):

Thanks, it work just fine.

Just like this:

```
// Create a request for the URL. 
WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV70/OData/$metadata");

//set the credentials.
request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

// Get the response.
WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

// Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

// Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

// Read the content.
string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

XmlDocument xmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
xmlDoc.Load(new StringReader(responseFromServer));

// Clean up the streams and the response.
reader.Close();
response.Close();
```

After this, just parse the data like a xml file.