# List of Collection Names in oData

Tags: c#, xamarin, odata, simple.odata

I am little of confused how to get list of collection names from the following odata service http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/

I just want to get a list of all of the available collection names in the service And then I'd like to let the user choose which collection to view information for, and subsequently show items in that collection

For example, the following line accessing to `Customers` collection.

```
var customers = client.For("Customers").FindEntriesAsync();
```

I could able to access inside of each collection as follows.

```
static void Main(string[] args) 
{ 

 var client = new ODataClient("services.odata.org/Northwind/Northwind.svc/");        

 var customers = client.For("Customers").FindEntriesAsync(); 

 foreach (var customer in customers) {   

     Console.WriteLine(customer["CustomerID"]); 
 } 
}
```

Comment: Question is somewhat unclear. You just want to get a list of all of the available collection names in the service? And then you'd like to let the user choose which collection to view information for, and subsequently show items in that collection?

Comment: Exactly. Yes I want to get list of  collection names and then let user choose which collection information for and so on.

Comment: And are you using `Simple.OData.Client`? https://github.com/object/Simple.OData.Client

Comment: Yes, I am using `Simple.OData.Client`.

Comment: I don't have time for an example, but this should help point you in the right direction to retrieve and parse the OData service's metadata http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11312512/odata-webservice-get-metadata-c-sharp

Comment: In particular, the answer pointing to using `Microsoft.Data.Edm.dll` for parsing the metadata retrieved via an HTTP request.

Comment: But I guess `Data.Edm` is not supported in Xamarin

Comment: In that case, you could parse it like a regular XML document as one of those answers suggests. If you look at http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/$metadata you should be able to see what nodes / info to look for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way that I can think of is:
When you get the response of this page: http://services.odata.org/V4/Northwind/Northwind.svc/ the response is an Atom feed and you can deal with it as an ATOM Feed or XML and basically load the XML and read the elements into your code and use them from there.

Comment: Yes that is my question, how could I deal with ATOM feed.